# How to open .bok file extension

Tags: file-types

I need to open .bok file but can't find a freely available tool to open it. I have tried freeFileViewer but it is displaying the file in HEX code. What tool do i need to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't try to find answer hardly, because it exist on first page of Google-search (for me): [File Extension .BOK Details](http://filext.com/file-extension/BOK). Mentioned on this page Drudix Book Designer led me to Drudix site and [Download page for Drudix Book Designer](http://www.drudix.com/Software_Download.aspx), where I can read:

> The version 2.8.39 can be downloaded furthermore in order to guarantee
>   the compatibility with the old file format .BOK. This file format is
>   not supported anymore in versions newer than 2.8.39.

Is it the answer on your question?

Comment: I have already tried a lot of setups from net. I will let you know if it works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

BOK file extension is associated with two types of files

1. TestGen Testbank File
   To open this file you can use: Pearson Education TestGen
2. ProStores Dynamic Web Page
   Edit with eBay ProStores
   View in a Web browser View in a Web browser

You can look at the page like this, the list of programs can be updated: [BOK file extension](http://www.fileextension.org/BOK)